# How to calculate "bang for buck" when less is better, not more

Tags: ratio

Ok let's say you have 3 products,

4lb bag costs $100

3lb bag costs $300

2lb bag costs $400

If I were asked, which product is more valuable, in the common sense, I would say, dividing dollars over lb, I get the value as follows:

4lb bag costs 100=25/lb

3lb bag costs 300=100/lb

2lb bag costs 400=200/lb

So it's clearly obvious that WOW, the first product is AMAZING value, amazing bang for my buck!

But how do you run this calculation if I want a product to be lighter and that's what is defined as more value? For example, sleeping bags, generally lighter bags are higher quality. So if I'm comparing these 3 sleeping bags, which one gives me more bang for my buck? (Please note I am NOT interested in advice on sleeping bags! I'm just using this as a possible example of something where less [weight] is better.)

If I just take the inverse and set to same denominator, I can get:

4lb bag costs $100 = 8/200

3lb bag costs $300 = 2/200

2lb bag costs $400 = 1/200

But that value is... difficult to explain and interpret. So for the first product, I'd say... each 8/200 of a dollar... does what? And how do I compare the values to find what's giving me the most bang for my buck?

Sorry if this problem doesn't belong here. I tried mathematics SE and they closed it. I honestly don't know where it should go but it is a real question!

Comment: Sleeping bags aren't priced per pound, they are priced per sleeping bag. With items like that "value" is harder to determine, and it's not only different for different kinds of item but different for different people. A mountain climber might pay a lot for a light bag. A car camper much less. A person who needs a sleeping bag for guests in their house doesn't care.

Comment: If you are car camping, buy the cheapest one.  If you are spending the summer hiking the Appalachian trail, buy the lightest one.  Value depends on your needs.

Comment: @gaefan i apologize i'm not asking about sleeping bags... that was just an example. this is more of a logic quesiton

Comment: @DJClayworth i apologize i'm not asking about sleeping bags... that was just an example. this is more of a logic quesiton

Comment: The point is that for things like sleeping bags (or anything else where you aren't paying "per quantity") there isn't a simple calculation.

Comment: The situation is that less weight is better but less weight costs more money. And then which selection is the best buy ?

Comment: @SSpring correct

Comment: Well, I have a computational method for the situation but it requires three parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a pretty common problem in economics, when looking at marginal utility versus marginal cost.

You start with a baseline product - in our case, the heaviest (and cheapest) bag:

Baseline:

- 4 lb for $100

Then look at alternatives:

- 3 lb for $300 = 1 lb savings for $200 = $200/lb saved
- 2 lb for $400 = 2 lb savings for $300 = $150/lb saved

Which seems to show that the 2 lb bag gives you the greatest overall value in terms of weight savings.

Or, you can look at the *marginal cost* of a lb saved over the previous item (ordered by weight):

- 3 lb for $300 = 1 lb savings for $200 = $200/lb saved
- 2 lb for $400 = 1 lb savings for $100 = $100/lb saved

Here, the 2 lb bag also gives you the greatest efficiency, but what if the value to you between a 3 lb bag and 4lb bag is very low? Is it worth spending an extra $100 for that second lb of weight savings? There are ways to quantify "marginal utility" in many cases (e.g. fuel savings with lighter cargo). In your particular example it may be purely subjective- as mentioned in the comments, it matters if you're only carrying the bag from your car to the tent, or whether you're carrying up Everest.

Comment: thank you for understanding my question! so what you're saying basically is that i have to have as a baseline the heaviest object and start from there. unlike with the reverse (how much lb for the $), you don't need to really have a baseline, just several options to compare

Comment: Or you could think of "nothing for $0" as your baseline and work up, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

As DJClayworth points out, sleeping bags are not normally sold by the pound. I've never gone to a sporting goods store and said, "I want to buy 20 pounds of sleeping bags."

To compare prices like this you have to be able to quantify value, that is, to put a number on it. And you have to be able to put a single number on it.

If you are comparing two boxes of the same cereal, and you can get a 3-pound box for $6 or a 2-pound box for $5, then the first box is $2/pound while the second is $2.50/pound, so the bigger box is the better deal. You could do such a calculation comparing two different brands of cereal, but then another factor would pretty clearly intrude: which cereal do you like better? If I can get corn flakes for $3/pound and raisin bran for only $2/pound, then you might say raisin bran is the better deal. But personally I don't like raisin bran, so to me the perceived value of corn flakes would be higher.

If you were comparing sleeping bags, and the ONLY thing you cared about was weight, than instead of calculating price per pound you could calculate price per inverse pound. That is, if a 4-pound sleeping bag costs $100 and a 2-pound bag costs $250, you could say that with the first bag you are paying $100/(1/4 inverse pounds)=$400 per inverse pound. With the second you are paying $250(1/2 inverse pounds)=$500 per pound. So the first is the better deal. But surely if comparing the value of sleeping bags you would also consider how effective they are at keeping you warm. A light sheet weighs less than a sleeping bag and is pretty cheap, but I wouldn't go on a hiking trip in sub-zero weather with a light sheet instead of a sleeping bag.

Furthermore, is the relevant function linear? That is, is a sleeping bag that weighs half as much twice as good? Or is half the weight 3 times as good? Or only 1 1/2 times as good?

To come up with a formula, you'd have to be able to define things precisely.